# Periods in table names causing errors

Tags: sql, postgresql, quoted-identifier

I am trying to update a table in pgadmin 3 (postgres 9.4) called: `assay.Luminex.Luminex_GT_shared.Analyte`

I kept getting the error:

```
ERROR:  improper qualified name (too many dotted names): 
assay.luminex.luminex_gt_shared.analyte
```

I have tested backquotes and brackets to no avail, keep getting syntax errors:

```
SELECT * FROM `assay.Luminex.Luminex_GT_shared.Analyte`;

SELECT * FROM [assay.Luminex.Luminex_GT_shared.Analyte];
```

I am a newb to SQL, I am just trying to make a simple update to a table and getting stuck on this.

Answer (score 5):

As [documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) in SQL, non-standard identifiers have to be quoted with double quotes:

```
SELECT * 
FROM "assay.Luminex.Luminex_GT_shared.Analyte";
```

But you should **really** avoid names like that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately I am working with a proprietary database so I don't have any control of their naming conventions!